# Cannot select angular modules in Yeoman angular generator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

Yeoman angular generator asks 'Which modules would you like to include ' and then shows some modules which can be included.

The prompt says that using using spacebar you can select or deselect the modules but I have tried both using spacebar and not using it

Neither the prompt changes with space or any button.

Pressing enter installs all dependencies but I want to install only few.

I am a new developer and I am learning. I am frustrated by trying many times but could not see solution.

Comment: Which generator are you using?

Comment: Yeoman generator angular

Comment: i have tried that generator.. space works just fine..

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved ..

The issue was with the 'Gulpfile' which is also referred in original repository.

[See here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1295)

The solution that worked was I changed the file with 
[this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1299)